# QPushButton has duplicated text after Qt upgrade

Tags: android, c++, qt, text, qpushbutton

I have an Android application written in C++ using Qt Creator.

After the Qt version upgrade (from **4.8** to **5.4**) I observed a strange behaviour: all QPushButton got duplicated text label, one is at the correct position and the other is shifted a bit away.
This behaviour can be observed on **Acer Iconia Tab A700** but not on other device (Samsung Galaxy Tab).

[image: illustration of the problem]

I have created a whole new QDialog menu in QT Creator, using just the graphical editor, but it displayed the same thing.

Did someone else observe the same thing?
I am quite new in Qt, and have no idea how to fix this...

#### EDIT

Here are some snippets:

**mydialog.ui**

```
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="startButton">
     <property name="sizePolicy">
      <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Minimum">
       <horstretch>0</horstretch>
       <verstretch>0</verstretch>
      </sizepolicy>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Start</string>
     </property>
     <property name="default">
      <bool>true</bool>
     </property>
    </widget>
```

**ui_mydialog.h**

```
public:
  QPushButton *startButton;
  QPushButton *stopButton;
...
void setupUi(QDialog *MyDialog)
{
    ... // some layout stuff here
    startButton = new QPushButton(MyDialog);
    startButton->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("startButton"));
    QSizePolicy sizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Minimum);
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0);
    sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0);
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(startButton->sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth());
    startButton->setSizePolicy(sizePolicy);
    startButton->setDefault(true);
... // later
QWidget::setTabOrder(startButton, stopButton);
}

void retranslateUi(QDialog *MyDialog)
{
    MyDialog->setWindowTitle(QApplication::translate("MyDialog", "Dialog", 0));
    startButton->setText(QApplication::translate("MyDialog", "Start", 0));
    stopButton->setText(QApplication::translate("MyDialog", "Stop", 0));
...
}
```

But again, I used the Qt Creator GUI to create the dialog, so my guess is that this should be some configuration error. Or maybe something related to the `retranslateUi()` function?

This is how it looks in Qt Creator:

[image]

**EDIT #2**

I dug up some instruction where the concrete style of the buttons were defined. Here it is:

```
    foreach (QToolButton* bt, listOfToolButtons) {
      bt->setAttribute(Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents);
      bt->installEventFilter(scrollAreaForToolBar);
      bt->setIconSize(QSize(iconSize, iconSize));
      bt->setStyleSheet("QToolButton{ background-color: #051a49; border: none;}");
      scrollAreaContainer->layout()->addWidget(bt);
    }
```

Comment: Can you share some of the code you're using?

Comment: Sure, but to be honest, I don't exactly know where to look for the bugs like this.

Comment: Interesting. Unless you've changed any of the code auto-generated by uic, I doubt that's the issue. Does it look strange in Qt Designer? Have you gone through the Qt bug tracker for similar reports?

Comment: Yep, nothing strange in Creator. And yes, I have looked trough the Qt bug tracker but nothing similar.

Comment: I don't have any other ideas. This smells like a bug to me, not something you've done wrong or incorrectly.

Comment: Other interesting fact: on a different device the entire UI looks different. I will look for the used style definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed some progress!

I had to recreate the entire widget and this time I gave a bit more size to it.
Just using QtCreator, **scaling the main frame of the widget**. Now, all button label is dispalyed correctly. Also, the size policy of the ui elements has been changed to **`Expanding`**.

Okay, I know that this is just a treatment and not a solution which explains why it occurs, but I am happy with this result now.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem,
I solved it by setting the stylesheet.
It seems to be a problem with the border,
the stylesheet that solve the problem is:

```
border-style: outset;
border-width: 2px;
border-radius: 4px;
border-color: black;
padding: 6px;
```

i tried different configuration but I cannot understand which is the real one that solve the problem.

Comment: Don't know about the above discussion on your answer, but this solved it for me, thanks.